# Escape characters in Handlebars for non-HTML files

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars to template out HTML and non-HTML files. I want to display the string `{{name}}` in the output served from the client. Is there a way to prevent Handlebars from processing this?

This is not a HTML file, so using `&#123;&#123;name&#125;&#125;` just displays as written (as it isn't parsed as HTML).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping?

Comment: To stop escaping try`{{{name}}}`

Comment: No, unfortunately `{{{name}}}` will print the unescaped contents of the `name` variable in the document. I actually want the characters `{{name}}` to appear in the document itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this. Handlebars has 2 ways of escaping a block from processing, either:

```
\{{name}}
```

or:

```
{{{{raw}}}}{{name}}{{{{/raw}}}}
```

both output `{{name}}`. (Although on my current version I couldn't get 4 braces to work properly.)

Ref: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#escaping-handlebars-expressions